# React router v5 Route tag not rendering enclosed component

Tags: reactjs

I just started learning/working with react router and got stuck with the very basic stuff.
If I am adding the `<Route>` , the enclosed component is not loading. Can anyone please help me on this. I even tried removing other components and just testing with route but then also it was not working

index.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './store/store'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>

    <BrowserRouter>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>

  </React.StrictMode >,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';
import Header from './components/Header';
import ProductCard from './components/ProductCard';
import ProductPage from './components/ProductPage';
import Cart from './components/Cart';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';


function App() {

  const showCartOption = useSelector(state => state.cart.showCartOption);
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.auth.isAuthenticated);

  return (
    <div class="m-3 shadow p-2">
      <Header></Header>
      <div class="row" >
        {(isAuthenticated && showCartOption) &&
          <Route path="/products">
            <ProductPage />
          </Route>}
        {(isAuthenticated && !showCartOption) &&
          <Route path="/cart">
            <Cart />
          </Route>
        }

        {!isAuthenticated && <LoginForm></LoginForm>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ProductPage.js:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ProductCard from "./ProductCard";



function ProductPage() {

    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    const productDescriptionLength = 75;
    const productTitleLength = 15;

    console.log("rendering : ");
    console.log(products);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("fetching products");

        const productResponse = fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(res => {
                console.log("resolved response : ");
                console.log(res);
                const translatedResponse = res.map(product => {
                    return {
                        productId: product.id,
                        productTitle: product.title.substring(0, productTitleLength) + "...",
                        productPrice: product.price,
                        productDescription: product.description.substring(0, productDescriptionLength) + "...",
                        productImage: product.image
                    }
                })

                return translatedResponse;
            })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                setProducts(res);
            });

    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-4 g-4">
            {
                products.length > 0 && products.map(product =>
                    <div class="col">
                        <ProductCard
                            productTitle={product.productTitle}
                            productPrice={product.productPrice}
                            productImage={product.productImage}
                            productDescription={product.productDescription}
                        />
                    </div>
                )
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default ProductPage;
```

cart.js:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import CartCard from "./CartCard";

function Cart() {

    const cartItems = useSelector(state => state.cart.cartItems);
    console.log("cartItems : ");
    console.log(cartItems);

    return (
        <div class="">
            {cartItems.length === 0 && <p class="m-5 text-center fs-1  shadow">Your cart is empty. Happy Shopping !</p>}

            {cartItems.length > 0 &&
                cartItems.map(cartItem => {

                    return <CartCard
                        productTitle={cartItem.productTitle}
                        productPrice={cartItem.productPrice}
                        productDescription={cartItem.productDescription}>
                    </CartCard>
                })
            }

        </div>
    );
}

export default Cart;
```

I am able to see the navbar but none of the enclosed components in route[image]

Comment: Can you show the code that switches to the "/products" path? It might also help if you include the url in the browser when you take the screen shot.

Comment: if I am using the path that I configured, nothing is changing. Its the same page.

Comment: What are the values of `showCartOption` and `isAuthenticated` when you do that?

Comment: those are in place
because if I am removing the Route tag, either of them loads properly

Comment: Both of those values have to be `true` in order for the Route to be rendered. Are they both true?

Comment: isAuthenticated is true
but why would it matter on showCartOption, because based on of its true or false, either of the route should be rendered, please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240438/discussion-between-hanchen-jiang-and-amit-gupta).

Comment: yeah, but in case showCartOption is false, is it not that cart page should render. 
```{(isAuthenticated && !showCartOption) &&
          <Route path="/cart">
            <Cart />
          </Route>
        }```

Comment: I see. You're saying neither route is displayed. Can you show code for cart as well?

Comment: just added it in the post

Answer (score 0):

Your routes should be inside of a Switch component in react router v5.

Something like this:

```
function App() {
    const showCartOption = useSelector((state) => state.cart.showCartOption);
    const isAuthenticated = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isAuthenticated);

    return (
        <div class='m-3 shadow p-2'>
            <Header></Header>
            <div class='row'>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/products'>
                        {isAuthenticated && showCartOption && <ProductPage />}
                    </Route>

                    <Route path='/cart'>
                        {isAuthenticated && !showCartOption && <Cart />}
                    </Route>

                    {!isAuthenticated && <LoginForm></LoginForm>}
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Read the documentation.
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: tried this as well. It did not work. You tried this ?

Comment: I'm not going to recreate your entire project, if you create a demo on codesandbox.io I'll help you fix it. Here is a basic example of it: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v5-k2zyb?file=/src/App.js. You should add a span in your routes as well to check if they are rendering and it's just the logic inside the rendered component. Also just confirm all your booleans.